# How to get string representation of PrimaryKeyRelatedField in JSON

Tags: python, json, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django REST Framework and I'm fairly newbie to this thing.

I want to have string representation for the manytomanyfield and foreignkey fields in my JSON output rather than the value.

**models.py**

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    """Movie objects"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    directorName = models.ForeignKey(Director)
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serialiazing all the Movies.
    """
    genre = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Genre.objects.all())
    directorName = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Director.objects.all())
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('popularity',"directorName",'genre','imdbScore','name','owner')
```

**JSON output**

```
{"popularity":"90.0","directorName":1,"genre":[1,2,3],"imdbScore":"8.9","name":"Titanic"}
```

instead of directorName's and genre's display_name, I'm getting only the values.

Please suggest me how to correct this.

**EDIT**
**[SOLVED]**
You need to override the to_representation() method of PrimaryKeyRelatedField as it returns the pk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**To do that, you need to override the `to_representation()` method of `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` as it returns the `pk`.**

You can create a `MyPrimaryKeyRelatedField` which inherits from `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` and then override its `to_representation()` method.

Instead of `value.pk` which `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` returned, return the string representation now. I have used [`six.text_type()`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.text_type) instead of `str()` to handle both the Python 2(unicode) and Python 3(str) versions.

```
from django.utils import six
from rest_framework import serializers

class MyPrimaryKeyRelatedField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        return six.text_type(value) # returns the string(Python3)/ unicode(Python2) representation now instead of pk
```

Your `serializers.py` would then look like:

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serialiazing all the Movies.
    """
    genre = MyPrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Genre.objects.all())
    directorName = MyPrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Director.objects.all())
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = ('popularity',"directorName",'genre','imdbScore','name','owner')
```

Comment: Gives me this error `'Director' object is not iterable`

Comment: Can you post the traceback.

Comment: Its resolved, actually I set `many=True` for `directorName` that's  why it gave me  `'Director' object is not iterable` error. But now I'm getting this thing instead of the string representation of `directorName` - `"directorName": "<rest_framework.relations.PKOnlyObject object at 0x7f40ac40ca50>",`

Comment: You need to add a  `__str__` method on your `Director` model. It should work then.

Comment: I added  `__unicode__` method as I'm using **Python2.7**

Comment: Okay. i have changed `str(value)` to `six.text_type(value)`. It should handle both Python2 and Python3 versions now.

Comment: `genre` giving correct representation only `directorName` making the problem. you can see the screenshot here https://www.dropbox.com/s/ntlea8e5l85app9/pic.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you try with the updated ans i.e `six.text_type(value)`

Comment: What does your `__unicode__` method in `Director` model return. Can you post your `Director`  model

Comment: `class Director(models.Model):
 """
 It holds the director informations.
 """
 name = models.CharField(max_length=40)

 def __unicode__(self):
  return self.name`

Comment: In your `__unicode__` method, try this: `return u'%s'%(self.name)`

Comment: You have to return a unicode value in `__unicode__` method.

Comment: I was getting the same `rest_framework.relations.PKOnlyObject` object as the value of `to_representation(self, value)`. My solution was to override `use_pk_only_optimization` to return `False` in my custom `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`, because of [this method](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L142).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest is probably to use [`StringRelatedField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield)

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    directorName = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True)

class Director(Model):
    # [...]
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.directorName
```

However, that does not work when you need different representations of the `Director` model. In that case you need to go with a custom serializer (see answer from Rahul Gupta).

Comment: but it gives me this error `'Relational fields should not provide a queryset argument, '`

Comment: That was a copy and past error on my part, `StringRelatedField` does not need/accept a queryset.